# How do I compare two 2-dimensional Arrays?

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, comparison

I have two 2-dimensional arrays that I would like to compare. I would like to change every element that differs between those two arrays.

1. The array elements must stay in the same order.
2. The operation will be executed very often.
3. The two-dimensional Arrays can be up to 100x100 elements large.

How would I best achieve this?

The first array is a matrix (let's assume 50x50, but this can vary). I will then do a few tests on each element and change the element if certain conditions match. The element is NOT changed in the first array, rather I save all elements in a second array.

The elements can either be "O" or " "(Space).
An example array could look like:

`@Array = ([" ", "O", "O", "O", " "], 
           [" ", "O", " ", " ", "O"], 
           ["O", "O", " ", "O", " "], 
           [" ", "O", "O", "O", "O"], 
           [" ", " ", " ", "O", " "])`

After each iteration (one iteration = all the checks ran on all elements), the new array is printed to the user. The reason I want to compare the arrays is that I would like to see which elements changed.

Some sample code of what I have so far:

```
foreach my $Row(@GameBoard) {
    foreach my $CurrentCell (@$Row) {
        <<COMPARE ELEMENT TO THE CORRESPONDING ELEMENT IN THE OTHER ARRAY HERE>>
    }
}
```

For some more information on what I'd like to do, this is a perl implementation of Conway's Game of Life. I have got it running fine, however, I would now like to "animate" the growth and death of cells ("O" -> "o" -> "." -> " ") before running the next iteration.

Comment: you mention "change" if corresponding elements differ. But what exactly to change about it? Please explain. Also, It would nice to have a example set of arrays you are talking about, with sample data.

Comment: Sample code helps troubleshoot. What have you got so far. Are the arrays definitely always the same geometry?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: try putting sample data in the format: `@arrayname1 = []` & `@arrayname2 = []`

Comment: I added some sample data, Array2 would be almost identical to Array (elements can only differ between "O" and " ").

Comment: You should record the changes during the checks.

Comment: @choroba How would I do this? For clarification: I do the checks on the first array and save the changed elements in the second array, because changing the first one directly would result in a bad output (I want to check all cells simulatenously, and changing a cell in the middle of the loop might have bad consequences for the checks of the others). After all the checks have been done on all the elements, I change the content of Array1 to match that of Array2 and print Array1.

Comment: @Bifrost: When saving a cell to array2, report it as changed if it's different to the corresponding cell in array1.

Comment: @Bifrost where exactly are you saving the results of this comparison to? You appear to be saving them to array 2, but you can't do that, because array 2 is one of the arrays that you're comparing!

Comment: @ialarmedalien I compare Array1 to Array2. If an element is "O" in Array1 and " " in Array2, I would like to save it as "o" in Array3. After doing this for the whole array, I would print the array, then compare Array1 and Array3. If an element is "O" in Array1 and "o" in Array3, it would become "." in Array3 (there would be more checks on Array3, for example if element is "O" in Array1 and "." in Array3, it would become " ").

Comment: @bifrost You've basically just written out what your code needs to do there. It should be easy to convert that into perl code now.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I know how to run through every element of one array, but how do I compare it to THE SAME element of the second array? I think that's what I am most confused about.

Comment: Think of it in terms of running through a set of coordinates, and accessing the array element in array1 and array2 for those coordinates -- e.g. `for my $x (0 .. 49) { for my $y (0 .. 49) { if ($array1[$x][$y] eq $array2[$x][$y]) ...` (etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(writing up my comment for posterity...)

Since your data set is two identical arrays-of-arrays of known size, the easiest way to think of it is as going through sets of coordinates, starting with (0,0) and going up to (49,49). You can compare the value in array 1 to that in array 2 for each set of coordinates, and storing the results for that position in the same place in array three.

Since you have two 50x50 arrays, the code would look like this:

```
for my $x (0 .. 49) {
    for my $y (0 .. 49) {
        # now compare $array1[$x][$y] to $array2[$x][$y]
        # results can be saved in $array3[$x][$y]
    }
}
```